# javascript cookie, little help please

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am displaying a div on my site, and I want to only display this div 5 times that the user has visited my site. So after 5 times, it wont show the div anymore.

I can do it with cookies. But Im only familiar with PHP. Javascript isn't my strong side.

Does anybody have a short piece of code to set a cookie, increase it for every visit, and if value is greater than 5 then don't show the DIV anymore?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say you have the variable visits in the cookies, you mainly use something similar to this

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
if (document.cookie.length>0)
  {
  c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  if (c_start!=-1)
    {
    c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
    c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
    if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
  }
return "";
}

var visits = getCookie("visits_number");

if (visists > 5)
    document.getElementById("your_div_name").setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidde");
```

Comment: Don't use `setAttribute` on an HTML document. There are many bugs in it in IE, one of which is that `style` won't work. Suggest `getElementById(...).style.display= 'none'`.

Answer (score 0):

[Quirksmode has an article discussing cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), which also includes three very handy helper functions (scroll down to the bottom). Read the article and all will become clear anyway.

Just remember that all information is stored as a string, and hence it is retrieved as a string. Therefore you should definitely be doing some manual type juggling before performing any operations on the data. See here:

```
var x = 1;
createCookie("myVar", x);

var newX = readCookie("myVar") + 1;

alert(newX); // "11"

// --- instead, do this: ---

var newX = parseInt(readCookie("myVar"), 10) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will have exactly the piece of code you are asking for, but it should be easy to compose it yourself, starting from these 2 necessary functions:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```